# Change data attribute in script

Tags: jquery, html

I've got an element on my page:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-nodeID="" class="quickView" data-target="#productModal" href="#">
```

And this element gets 'repeated' in using a serialized ajax object and what I'm trying to do is change the data-nodeID attribute but I can't seem to alter it. I've tried finding the element by it's class name:

```
$(myTemplate).find('.quickView').attr({'data-nodeid': product.Id});
```

Does anyone know how this is done, please?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at jQuery [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) documentation.

> `.attr(attributeName, value)`
>
> **attributeName**
>   *Type: String*
>   The name of the attribute to set.
>
> **value**
>   *Type: String or Number or Null*
>   A value to set for the attribute. If null, the specified attribute will be removed (as in .removeAttr()).

---

Also be careful about uppercase letters when you try to set your attribute :

```
$(myTemplate).find('.quickView').attr('data-nodeID', product.Id);
```

Comment: Perfect, turns out it was a mistake in me populating the ID (as it was null) corrected that and all is well. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using jQuery [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```js
// $(myContainer).find('.quickView').data('nodeid', product.Id);

$('#myContainer').data('customTag', 2);

console.log($('#myContainer').data('customTag'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myContainer" data-custom-tag="1"></div>
```